# React native booking library

Tags: react-native, calendar

Does anyone know any good react-native booking library for scheduling appointment sessions besides the React Native Calendars https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendars

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this library: [react-native-calendar-events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-events)

I've used it for fetching calendar events from the native iOS & Android (Google) calendar.